# key values set in LocalStorage accessible by other applications

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

I am building a small application  using ionic3. For the database, I am using FireStore. But in order to reduce the amount of data being transmitted over the network, I decided to "cache" some useful info in my localstorage. Now, my worry is, if there is another applicationon on the device also using LocalStorage, and by coincidence, it has same keys (for example a key `members` to keep list of members) as mine to store data, will it change data I access on my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [LocalStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) use [SQLite storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite), it store data in a private directory binded to the app using it (and not a global directory).

So no, your data while not change **in your app** (but in your browser, if you use the same IP and port, it will consider it's the same app, so it will change your data).

Comment: Thanks! I know it uses the SQLiteStorage but only when present. So I guess to be safe I'll add the SQLite plugin before installing app in the device...?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue It's a dependance of localstorage, so I think you already installed it (if you have follow the doc)